# How can I relay video to a TV (has only RCA input) from RaspberryPI (model B+)?

Tags: composite-video

Please specify the necessary components required to connect a Raspberry Pi to a TV with only an RCA input.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a cable with a Tip-Ring-Ring-Sleeve (TRRS) connector on one end, and (normally) 3 RCA connectors on the other, coloured red, white and yellow. The red and white RCA plugs carry right and left audio signals, while the yellow RCA connector carries the video signal.

[image: TRRS to RCA cable]